# Javascript onClick on button

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="ch6">ch6 data</div>
        <p><input id='button6' type='submit' value='read ch6'/></p>

       $("#button6").click(function(){
    $("#button6").hide();
        });
```

I clicked on button6 input button,but the $("#button6").click(function() is not being called.

Comment: Can I assume your javascript is between <script> tags?  and if so can I also assume that your registering the click event in the $(document).ready() function?

Comment: A submit button is going to refresh the page. Is that the real problem here?

Answer (score -4):

Notice that inline code is not recomended for security issues... [read more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)

#### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dayol/1/edit)

```
<div id="ch6">ch6 data</div>
<p><input id='button6' type='submit' value='read ch6'/></p>
<script>
  var b6 = $("#button6");
  b6.click(function(){
    b6.hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You should probably register the click within a $(document).ready().  The way you coded this, with the inline script tag after the element, would work.  However for safety sake, utilizing the $(document).ready() is a good idea.

Comment: @john: what exactly is "unsafe" with this approach?

Comment: @john is right ... this is just a fast way to show a soution ... I updated the answer!